# If $\int_1^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\leqslant f^2(x)$ for all $x\geqslant 1$, prove that $f(x)\geqslant\frac{1}{2}\,(x-1).$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[1,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a positive, continuous function. 
>   If $\int_1^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\leqslant f^2(x)$ for all $x\geqslant 1$, prove that $f(x)\geqslant\frac{1}{2}\,(x-1).$

*Attempt.* Usual procedures, like working on the monotonicity of the function $$g(x):=f(x)-\frac{1}{2}\,(x-1)$$ (in order to get $g$ increasing and therefore $g(x)\geqslant g(1)=f(1)>0$ for $x\geqslant 1$), do not work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h(t)=f(1+t)$. We want to show that if $h:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is a continuous function such that 
$$ \forall x>0,\quad\int_{0}^{x}h(t)\,dt \leq h(x)^2 \tag{A}$$
then $h(x)\geq \frac{x}{2}$. Let $H(x)=\int_{0}^{x}h(t)\,dt$. We have that $H$ is a positive, $C^1$ and increasing function fulfilling
$$ \frac{H'(x)}{\sqrt{H(x)}} \geq 1 \tag{B}$$
and by integrating both sides of $(B)$ on $(0,z)$ we get
$$ 2\sqrt{H(z)} \geq z \quad \leftrightarrow\quad H(z)\geq\frac{z^2}{4}.\tag{C}$$
The tricky part is just to convert this bound for $H(z)$ into a bound for its derivative:

$$ h(x)\geq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{x}h(t)\,dt}\geq\sqrt{\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{\int_{0}^{t}h(u)\,du}\,dt}=\sqrt{\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{H(t)}\,dt}\geq\sqrt{\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{2}\,dt}=\frac{x}{2}.\tag{D} $$
As a faster alternative, we may just invoke $(B)$ once again.

Comment: I don't see why you need that last 'tricky part'. You have shown that $\frac{H'(x)}{\sqrt{H(x)}} \geq 1$ and that $H(x) \geq \frac{x^2}{4}$. A lower bound for $h(x) = H'(x)$ follows directly from these two results.

Comment: Since you proved $H(x)\geq x^2/4$, wouldn't you get $h(x)\geq\sqrt{H(x)}\geq x/2$ for all $x>0$? (and avoid the last inequality?)

Comment: @Winther: no, because $f(x)\geq g(x)$ does not imply, in general, $f'(x)\geq g'(x)$.

Comment: Your first result says $H'(x) \geq \sqrt{H(x)}$. This is what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Winther: oh, you mean that, I see. Then I agree, $(D)$ can be replaced by $(B)$, of course.